# MPDF Error when page is longer than 1 page

Tags: php, mpdf

I am new to MPDF 7, I was working with it last on V5 last so please excuse if I am asking a simple question...

I am using MPDF to generate a PDF file which contains a couple tables which can be 2 lines long each, or 2000 lines each, but it appears when I add enough data (tables or rows to a single table) to extend past the first page, I am getting an error: `must precede in a table` on a white screen.

Does anybody have an idea why I would get this?

My MPDF call is as follows:

```
$variables = [
            'mode' => 'C', 
            'format' => 'A4', 
            'orientation' => 'P',
            'setAutoTopMargin'  => 'stretch',
            'setAutoBottomMargin'  => 'stretch',
            'debug' => true,
            'autoPageBreak' => true
        ];
$mpdf = new Mpdf($variables);
```

Any assistance would be great thanks guys

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for the link... But correct me if I am wrong, but the default page break status should work? or is there a variable I specifically need to change?
I checked the link you posted, but I am not 100% sure what I am missing, if I am missing something...